# Java static variable update with quartz scheduler

Tags: java

I have a JobClass wherein I am calling another class named as MainClass. The quartz trigger schedule to run the Main class via JobClass every 5 minutes. Now in the main class I have to collect the current date time something like below:-

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String CurrentDateTime = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

public  String[] splitMe = CurrentDateTime.split("/"); 
public  String year = splitMe[0];
public  String month = splitMe[1];
public  String day = splitMe[2];
public  String hour = splitMe[3];
public  String minute = splitMe[4];
public  String second = splitMe[5];


String FilePrefix = year.concat(month).concat(day).concat("_").concat(hour).concat(minute).concat(second);
String FilePrefix4ControlFile = year.concat(month).concat(day).concat(" ").concat(hour).concat(minute).concat(second);
String EarliestTime = year.concat("-").concat(month).concat("-").concat(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(day) - 1));
String LatestTime = year.concat("-").concat(month).concat("-").concat(day);
```

This way I can get all my date time individual variable to create some strings with different combinations. Every single job runs I need to have a unique set of values however whatever number of times these variables are called within one job run then the values should be same.

Now I tried doing it using Static variables which kind of solved one problem of having same values during 1 run. However as the static variables are created on class initialisation ( main class) then they will always have same value unless the class is reloaded which I don't want to do , indeed not that easily possible in java.

I am sure I am doing some silly mistake, any pointers on this will be helpful.

PS: I just started Java by my own recently.

Thanks guys!
RJay

Comment: Code above doesn't show any use of "static", should post code that illustrates your question.  In my opinion you're doing double work by formatting the date to a string and then splitting it, why not instantiate a GregorianCalendar and fetch out date components directly?  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: public static String FilePrefix = null;
 static
 {
  
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  FilePrefix = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
  System.out.println(FilePrefix);
 }